# Friendship System Sql Structure & Query

Tags: php, sql, mysql, join

I am coding a friendship system and it has two tables.

**members**

- id
- username
- password

**friends**

- id
- user_id
- friend_id
- status

Let's say that i want a query that can select the friends IDs of the member $userId how possible to make this in one query?

I found a solution which is to make 2 queries. The fist selects the friends WHERE `user_id = $userId` AND the second selects friends WHERE `friend_id = $userId` and then MIX them in one array. If there is no other solution I'm going to use it.

please any ideas for both the SQL structure & Queries?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use:

```
SELECT f.friend_id
  FROM FRIENDS f
 WHERE f.user_id = $user_id
UNION
SELECT t.user_id
  FROM FRIENDS t
 WHERE t.friend_id = $user_id
```

Using `UNION` will remove duplicates.  `UNION ALL` would be faster, but it doesn't remove duplicates.

If you want to get the information for the friends from the `MEMBERS` table, use:

```
SELECT m.*
  FROM MEMBERS m
  JOIN (SELECT f.friend_id 'user_id'
          FROM FRIENDS f
         WHERE f.user_id = $user_id
        UNION
        SELECT t.user_id
          FROM FRIENDS t
         WHERE t.friend_id = $user_id) x ON x.user_id = m.id
```

BTW: I hope you're using [mysql_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-escape-string.php) on the variables, otherwise you risk SQL injection attacks:
[image]

Comment: Your code is just what i need! much appreciated. Accepted your answer.

Comment: function safeDB($text){
    return mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags(trim($text)));
}

I believe this is fine :)

Comment: @amindzx: Cool, just checking.  Some people get rabid over SQL injection attacks

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to try using

```
SELECT  m.*
FROM    friends f INNER JOIN
        members m ON f.friend_id = m.user_id
WHERE   f.user_id = $userId
```

This will give you all the **Friends** details

To get BOTH have a look at

```
SELECT  DISTINCT CASE WHEN f.user_id = $userId then f.friend_id else f.user_id END CASE
FROM    friends f 
WHERE   f.user_id = $userId
OR      f.friend_id = $userId
```

Comment: it seems complicated but i am going to try it. Thanks, can you recommend any good resource to learn about this?

Comment: This is pretty standard Sql. Do you require Sql Help?

Comment: #1054 - Unknown column 'master.user_id' in 'on clause'

Comment: Have a look again... Sorry autocomplete broke it there.

Comment: That will only return the user_id's friends, and not include where other people have friended the user_id

Comment: #1054 - Unknown column 'm.user_id' in 'on clause' 
hmm i don't know why :(

Comment: @amindzx: Because the column is `id`, not `user_id` in the `MEMBERS` table.  @astander: Hope you don't mind that I editted your answer to correct that.

Comment: @astander: I write it in Notepad too.  Can't say I didn't give you anything for xmas =)

Answer (score 1):

Why not inserting 2 rows for 1 friendship. For example:

Let's say we have 2 user will become friends

User_id : 1 &
Friend_id : 2

```
insert into friends (user_id, friend_id, status) values (1,2,0)    
insert into friends (user_id, friend_id, status) values (2,1,0)
```

so you can select easily by simple select query.

Also it will ease the pain for your likely next question "How to find Mutual Friends".

Answer (score 0):

Since you're asking for something simple like:

```
SELECT friend_id FROM friends WHERE user_id = id; [fill in the id]
```

I'll give you something fancier:

```
SELECT * FROM members AS m
WHERE m.id
IN (SELECT f.friend_id FROM friends AS f
  WHERE f.user_id = (SELECT pm.id FROM members AS pm
    WHERE pm.username = 'amindzx'));
```

Granted using a join over a sub-query would be better.

Also, there's no need for an `id` in the friends column, because only one relationship between a `user_id` and a `friend_id` should exist; these can both be described as the `id` columns in unison.

Comment: You are totally right about the ID, but does this query can get if friend_id is linked to user_id as well without duplicating?? i mean the inverse.

Comment: I would love to answer your question, but I do not understand what you mean. By "the inverse" do you mean you'd like to find all users that have a particular friend? That would look like `select user_id from friends where friend_id = 1` (assuming 1 = the id of the user in question).